# Counting number of consecutive years in a range in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time

I need to count the number of contiguous years in a data frame. I want to filter data frames that have more than 30 years of consecutive records. Before I was doing:

```
(length(unique(Daily_Streamflow$year)) > 30
```

But I realized that the number of years (unique years) could be more than 30 but not in a consecutive range, for example:

```
 (unique(DSF_09494000$year))
 [1] 1917 1918 1957 1958 1959 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980
[27] 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
[53] 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
```

How is possible to count the number of years in a range that is continuous without missing years? Is there a similar function as `na.contiguous` of `stats` package but for non-NA values?

Comment: Eventually you can use `rle(diff(...)==1)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326939/r-is-there-a-way-to-count-the-number-of-consecutive-numbers-in-each-row https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785911/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-years-in-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of consecutive years in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785911/counting-the-number-of-consecutive-years-in-r)